# Access variables from other classes

Tags: java, class, variables, object, abstract-class

I have a class that is receiving input from users. Then the results are parsed and stored in this class I placed below. Then there is a separate class that is taking what is stored in the class below and creating something with it. I would post all of the classes, but there are just too many lines of code. I have placed below the exact class I have a question on (minus other variables of the same type for simplicity)
 I would like to know if there is a way to access variables from an abstract class within another class.  Here is my abstract class:

```
public abstract class ParsResults {

    public String AnsName;

    public String AnsType;

}
```

Then I have another class that needs these variables.  Im just not sure how to approach it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the other class a sub-class? Also, please follow Java naming conventions (`name`).

Comment: Well if you _extend_ this class from another class the variables will all be accessible.  In fact, because you made the variables `public` they are accessible anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: you access information from *objects* not from classes, much less *abstract* classes. Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Think through your problem a bit more and then tell us the details of exactly what it is you're trying to do, not how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: While what @TimBiegeleisen states is true, know that inheritance is often not the best solution for sharing data. Again, your overall problem is much more important here than is how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree completely...just ran out of space to type.

Comment: You're still asking how to solve a specific coding problem and less how to solve an over-all issue. Note that for one the fields of this class should be *private* and there should be public getter methods for any fields that need to have their state exposed.

Comment: I did not write the class. I am only supposed to have to edit the class that needs the variables in order to make the program work

Comment: And I state again: you don't access variables from classes, you access them from objects, and how and where you have the objects, and what references you have to the objects, makes all the difference. I fear that you're not telling us near enough to understand your underlying problem.

Comment: [Lesson: Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is absolutely no way accessing instance variables of instances of abstract classes, since they can not have instances.
2. Please do not make instance variables public, make them private and provide getters and setters.
3. Your instance variables should start with a lowercase letter.
4. If you have an instance of a concrete subclass of `ParsResults`, you can access its values using the getters (see point 2.).

Answer (score -1):

To share variables between classes, there are three ways:

```
    public class Human {

    // instance variables 
    public String name;
    public int age; 

    //constructor, creates an instance of the Human class. 
    public Human(String s, int i){

    name = s;
    age = i;
    }

}
```

in this case, your instance variables are public. 
so in another class, when you create a instance of a Human class by calling:

```
Human aHuman = new Human(tom, 25);
```

then you can access the two instance variables directly. you can get its value by using:

```
String theHumanName = aHuman.name;
```

and you can set its value(change it) by using:

```
aHuman.name = "mike";
```

the two above lines will only work if your variables are public.
the reason you should make them private is to keep the values from being changed from outside the class. So if they are private then you create get and set methods, depending on the need.
Here is how it should be done:

```
    public class Human {

    // instance variables 
    private String name;
    private int age; 

    //constructor, creates an instance of the Human class. 
    public Human(String s, int i){

        setName(s);
        setAge(i);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
     public String getName() {
     return name;
    }

    /**
    * @param name the name to set
    */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
}

}
```

now from outside the class, you can call:

```
    String theHumanName = aHuman.getName();       // this a method call, therefore you must have the parentheses
```

and you can set its value(change it) by using:

```
aHuman.setName("mike");
```

Comment: The third way is passing the data as arguments to a constructor, example is when I created the 'aHuman' instance.

Answer (score -2):

You have to instatiate that class, but you can't instantiate an abstract class.
So first create a not abstract class witch extends ParsResults, then instantiate this new class and in your main you can see the variables like this:

```
public class NewClass extends ParsResults {

    //...

}


    public static void main(String [] args){

        NewClass nc = new NewClass();

        // ...

        System.out.println(nc.Name);

    }
```